# How to allow someone to correct their Cognito Form submission

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm trying to have people go back in after they've submitted the form and fix things.  I've marked the entries incomplete and want to, whenever the form is deemed incomplete, have an automatic email response sent to the enterer asking them to complete other details.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed description of how to automatic the process of asking your customers to make changes after they have submitted their [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

**Enable Link Sharing**

Under `Build` - `Form Settings`:

1. Turn on `Entry Link Sharing`
2. Set `Allow Edit Links` to `Always`
3. Click on the email template to customize the email that will be used when you share view/edit links with your customers.
4. Make sure to specify the field on your form that contains the email address of your customer

[image: turn on entry link sharing]

**Enable Save & Resume**

Under `Build` - `Submission Settings`, enable `Save & Resume`:

[image: turn on save & resume]

**Share Edit Links**

Under `Entries`, select the entry you want your customer to update and follow these steps:

1. Click `Share` above the entry
2. Under `Share a Link` - `Edit Link`, select `Link Expires` - `When Submitted`
3. Click `Get Link` to mark the entry as `Incomplete` and create an edit link for the entry

[image: share entry edit link]

4. Further customize the sharing message to provide instructions and click Send

[image]

You customer will then receive the email asking them to make changes, including a link to edit their submission.  They will be able to edit the entry, including saving incremental changes, until they click Submit.  When they click submit, they will no longer be able to make changes using this link and the normal submission emails and integrations will be kicked off.